# Access Request parameters inside Symfony2 DataTransformer

Tags: php, forms, symfony

Is it possible to get value from another form field inside DataTransformer for a field?

I can create an invitation linked to an email, then when the user register he must type an invitation code, it will work even if that code is not linked to the email he's entered, because `Invitation` field is a `DataTransformer` that checks the value inside DB. I would like to check inside that query, if the email exists.

**MainForm**

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('invitation', 'invitation_type', array(
            'required' => true,
            'label' => false,
            'attr' => array(
                'placeholder' => 'form.invitation_code',
                'class' => 'form-control',
            )
        ))
    ;
}
```

`invitation_type` is a service where I inject entityManager to a fieldtype that renders the dataTransformer:

**InvitationType**

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $transformer = new InvitationTransformer($this->entityManager);
    $builder->addModelTransformer($transformer);
}
```

And then the transformer

```
public function reverseTransform($value)
{
    $invitation = $this->entityManager->getRepository('Invitation')
        ->findOneBy(array(
            'code' => $value
        ));

    return $invitation;
}
```

That's the query, which as I said is working without checking the email value, it would be something like `'email' => $emailValue` but, I don't know how to access `$emailValue`

Comment: in the doc seem that you can apply a datatransformer to the entire form, but is marked as wrong... you can try and see if you can manipulate data

Comment: @Matteo Seems a good solution but I think I would need to type a lot of lines to bypass fields I don't want to transform and change values for what I want...

Comment: of course, otherwise you can build a form type with both the value and apply the transformer to it....

Comment: But then we have the same problem, how we pass/access the second parameter in `transform()` and `reverseTransform()` methods? That's the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can inject your value into transformer

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $entity = $builder->getData();
    $email = $entity->getEmail();

    $transformer = new MyTransformer($email);

    $builder->add(
        $builder->create('sample', 'choice', array(
            'attr'     => array('class' => 'test')
        ))->addModelTransformer($transformer)
    )

}

class MyTransformer implements DataTransformerInterface {

    private $emailValue;

    public function __construct($emailValue)
    {
        $this->emailValue = $emailValue;
    }

    public function reverseTransform($value)
    {

        // Do something with $this->emailValue;

        $invitation = $this->entityManager->getRepository('Invitation')
            ->findOneBy(array('code' => $value));

        return $invitation;
    }

}
```

Comment: But how do I inject `$emailValue` from the form field? I mean, `$emailValue` must be the value of `email` input field when submitted. So, when we submit the form, transformer checks for `code` and `email` at entityManager

Comment: $builder->getData(); get the current entity and you can access any field. I updated my answer above.

Comment: But `$builder->getData();` is always null, that's why I didn't use that method before asking here. I've updated my question to show full code.

Comment: Strange, I have the form entity in $builder->getData()

Comment: That's because you are using it from insithe the mainform (in my case) and not in the child field type (service in my case) that adds the DataTransformer view. Inside that custom field type (`invitation_type` in my case) $builder doesn't has any entity related, but `mainForm` does, because it's the root form.

Comment: In this case, not need to inject $this->entityManager into transformer, inject directly the variable

Comment: `entityManager` is needed to perform the query to find if that invitation exists...

Answer (score 0):

So if someone has the same problem I've found a solution.

First create a service for your custom field type, injecting `@request_stack`

```
foo.form.type.invitation:
    class: Foo\BarBundle\Form\Type\InvitationType
    arguments: [ "@doctrine.orm.entity_manager" ]
    tags:
        - { name: form.type, alias: invitation_type}
    calls:
        - [setRequest, [@request_stack]]
```

Then create your custom field type class, which will inject our `Request` to the `DataTransformer`

```
<?php

namespace Foo\BarBundle\Form\Type;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use Foo\BarBundle\Form\DataTransformer\InvitationTransformer;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RequestStack;

class InvitationType extends AbstractType
{
    private $entityManager;

    protected $request;

    public function __construct(EntityManager $em)
    {
        $this->entityManager = $em;
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $transformer = new InvitationTransformer($this->entityManager, $this->request);
        $builder->addModelTransformer($transformer);
    }

    public function getParent()
    {
        return 'text';
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'invitation_type';
    }

    public function setRequest(RequestStack $request_stack)
    {
        $this->request = $request_stack->getCurrentRequest();
    }
}
```

And then our `DataTransformer` needs to fetch the data, change values to match your requests, of course

```
<?php
namespace Foo\BarBundle\Form\DataTransformer;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use Symfony\Component\Form\DataTransformerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Exception\UnexpectedTypeException;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class InvitationTransformer implements DataTransformerInterface
{
    protected $entityManager;
    protected $request;

    public function __construct(EntityManager $entityManager, Request $request)
    {
        $this->entityManager    = $entityManager;
        $this->request          = $request;
    }

    public function transform($value)
    {
        if (null === $value) {
            return null;
        }

        if (!$value instanceof Invitation) {
            throw new UnexpectedTypeException($value, 'Foo\BarBundle\Entity\Invitation');
        }

        return $value->getCode();
    }

    public function reverseTransform($value)
    {
        if (null === $value || '' === $value) {
            return null;
        }

        if (!is_string($value)) {
            throw new UnexpectedTypeException($value, 'string');
        }
        $formData = $this->request->get('registration_form'); // Your MAIN form goes here
        $email = $formData['email']; // The value you need
        $invitation = $this->entityManager->getRepository('FooBarBundle:Invitation')
            ->findOneBy(array(
                'code'  => $value,
                'email' => $email
            ));

        if($this->entityManager->getRepository('FooBarBundle:User')->findOneBy(array("invitation" => $invitation))){
            return null;
        }

        return $invitation;
    }
}
```

Now you have access to your parameters bag inside your `DataTransformer`, piece of cake.